# Vim: always navigate to set column when changing line

Tags: vim

Is there an equivalent in Vim to the idea of a "goal column" in Emacs?

I'd like to set a goal column, so whenever I navigate to a new line in Insert mode, the cursor is automatically positioned at that given column.

e.g I have the text:

```
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
```

I type `123<space>` in between `foo bar` on the first line and then have (pipe symbol shows where my cursor is):

```
foo 123 |bar
foo bar
foo bar
```

I press the down arrow... and I end up here:

```
foo 123 bar
foo bar|
foo bar
```

But I want to end up here:

```
foo 123 bar
foo |bar
foo bar
```

The use case being that I'm typing a list of numbers to insert in some existing text, and I want to just whizz through by typing a number, then pressing down, then next number, down, number, down, number, down, etc, without having to reposition my cursor each time.

Comment: Tried it with a macro ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a macro - position to the column and then:

```
:map ,1 i123 <Esc>bj
```

... and keep typing <kbd>,1</kbd>; or you could use Vim's macro recording feature (`:help recording`):

```
qai123 ^[bjq
```

(that stores the macro in a register 'a', the final <kbd>q</kbd> ends recording).

Then you can use a repeat count (from the appropriate column) and invoke the recorded macro with <kbd>@a</kbd>:

```
100@a
```

If you want to enter different text each time, and just have a smarter next-line feature, you can create a macro for that:

```
:imap ,, <Esc>j5^V|i
```

That ^V is a literal <kbd>Control-V</kbd>, entered by typing <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> twice; the next char is a pipe, which will move the cursor to column 5.

You'd use this macro in input mode, entering the digits, then a space, then **,,** which would move you to the next line at column 5, still in input mode.
Then when you're done: `:iunmap ,,`

Comment: Excellent, the second part of your answer solves the problem.  I wasn't previously aware of imap, and I can see it's going to be extremely useful.